# How can I change the enter key to another in VSCODE, key since my laptop's enter key is broken?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have damaged the enter key of my laptop. I can change it in the operating system (ubuntu) with this  'xmodmap -e "keycode 115=KP_Enter"' and it really works on almost everything, but this does not work for me in VSCODE.

Comment: You can try opening your key bindings (`ctrl + K, ctrl + S`) and searching for `"Enter"` (quotes included). But you might need the enter key to change anything.

Comment: @ConnorLow I don't think it is possible to remap basic keys (like any letter on your keyboard, or the enter key) from Visual Studio Codes keyboard shortcuts.  These deal with _shortcuts_ only.

Comment: *"not in Visual Studio Code"* Then why mention VSC at all? Try asking this on https://askubuntu.com/ OR https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  sorry, my question is how do I change the key in VSCODE

Comment: You can install AutoKey for Ubuntu or AutoHotkey for windows and create a script that only maps the key for VSCODE, i.e. map the key when VSCODE has focus, otherwise map it to it's default. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/292019/how-to-map-my-enter-key-to-a-different-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use another text editor since it was impossible to change the key in VSCODE